# Why can't I return an IPagedList to my Post action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This sounds simple in theory (and it probably is)
I have a view from a Get ActionResult using @model IPagedList
As the model.
I also have a form on the view and when user clicks submit, the code jumps to the post action,
However it throws an error when I try to include IPagedList traclerlist as a parameter in the Post ActionResult.

“Cannot create an instance of an interface”

Tried ICollection and IList and get the same result ?
Any Ideas?  Need code ?
Please note this is an MVC 3 application using razor views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what the model binder is doing. The model binder constructs instances of a class and then uses form values, etc. to populate your model. You are telling the model binder to construct an instance of an interface, which it cannot do. Is it supposed to choose a random class that implements IPagedList? How do you expect that to work?

Comment: ok, clearly I need to work on my understanding of interfaces. So what is my simplest approach to this, how to return a list of objects back to my Post action ?

Comment: Simplest approach is to have your post action use the class you defined that implements IPagedList.

Comment: Do you mean within the TrackerModel class add the following ?...public PagedList<TrackerModel> TrackerModels { get; set; } and in the controller use...PagedList<TrackerModel> TrackerModels ??

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code but that sounds like that's what you would want. Instead of IPagedList you'd use the actual PagedList class.

Comment: Or so I thought , I put the above into my code and I'm getting "No parameterless constructor defined for this object", the return of my get action is - "return View("SetMultipleStatus", pagedList);", where pagedList was declared as "IPagedList<TrackerModel> pagedList = customerViewList.ToPagedList(filter.Page, filter.PageSize, totalRecords);" within the action...... so why won't the same post back when form submitted....with the Post action parameters "public ActionResult SetMultipleStatus(int? page, IPrincipal user, PagedList<TrackerModel> pagedList)"?

Answer (score 1):

IPagedList is an interface.  You cannot create an instance of this class.  It is designed to be a definition for a class for you to inherit from.